Concatenate C macros with compile-time expression result
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define VAL1 8
    #define _CONCAT(name, v) name##v
    #define CONCAT(name, v) _CONCAT(name, v)

    void main()
    {
        int CONCAT(var, VAL1) = 5;
        printf("%d\n", var8);
    }

I want to use macro concatenation with expression results. Compiles OK but the following does not compile:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define VAL1 4
    #define VAL2 2
    #define _CONCAT(name, v) name##v
    #define CONCAT(name, v) _CONCAT(name, v)

    void main()
    {
        int CONCAT(var, VAL1 * VAL2) = 5;
        printf("%d\n", var8);
    }

Tried in gcc and got an error.

got an error - If you got an error, you should include the exact error message in your question, got an error alone is not sufficient.

The C preprocessor will not resolve C math operations in macro expansion.
Your first case compiles because int CONCAT(var, VAL1) = 5; results in int var8 = 5, which is valid.
In the second case, int CONCAT(var, VAL1 * VAL2) = 5 is expanded to int var4 * 2 = 5, which doesn't make sense.

VAL1 * VAL2 results in an integer constant expression so it is resolved at compile-time. However, compile-time does not necessarily mean during preprocessing. Preprocessing happens before the meaning of the resulting C code is evaluated by the compiler, so therefore you cannot use preprocessor tricks like ## in this case.
In general it is a bad idea to create variable/function names from preprocessor macros.

In general, integer constant expressions don't even have to be evaluated at compile time.  There are some contexts in which they must be, but others where they could be (but probably aren't) evaluated at runtime.

@JohnBollinger It is most helpful for beginners to always consider them evaluated at compile-time or they may get very strange ideas regarding performance.

Except when those beginners then wrongly assume that it makes sense to expect to be able to access the result of such an evaluation via the preprocessor.

Thanks I am not a beginner (40 years experiance) I asumed it will not work tried to see if someone has a trick to resolve it thank you all

Look at the output of gcc -E on this source (after removing the #include lines which would generate a lot of output):
# 0 "78870302.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "78870302.c"






void main()
{
    int var4 * 2 = 5;
    printf("%d\n", var8);
}

int var4 * 2 = 5; is not syntactic C.

In passing - main() needs to return int, not void.
